# Is there a way in PowerShell to truncate a string without cutting short a word

Tags: powershell

I've been looking around and haven't been able to find anything. I would like to truncate a string without cutting a word short. Like an excerpt.

```
$string = "This is my string"

9 = "This is m"
```

Ideally would like `"This is my"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$string.Substring(0, $string.IndexOf(" ", 9))
```

Should do what you want, i.e. it starts at the character number you give it, looks for the next space, and cuts the string short there.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `$string.Substring(0,$string.lastindexof(" "))` ?

Comment: Thank you very much Ocaso for your contribution. Again works lovely.